# How do i ensure the contents of all my textboxes in a windows are not null? using ForEach statement

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, foreach

i want to authenticate text boxes in vb.net and wpf ensuring it does not contain a null value before i feed their contents to a database, i am thinking of using the for...each statement but its not working in wpf.Here is my code.

```
for Each txt as Control in window.controls
  if typeof is Textbox Then
    if txt.text = "" Then
      MsgBox("Complete the blank Properties")
      exit sub
    end if
  end if
next
```

This code does not work and i get an error: "window is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys i finally solved the Problem, Thanx alot for your suggestions.

This is just a function that you call to loop through all textboxes in a grid and make sure they are not empty, you call the function and pass the name of the grid as the parameter.

Cheers!

```
public function AuthenticateTextBoxes(Byref G as Grid)
For i as int32 = 0 to (G.Children.count - 1)
  if G.Children.Item(i).GetType = GetType(TextBox) Then
     Dim txt as Textbox = CType(G.Children.Item(i),TextBox)
       if string.IsnullOrWhitespace(txt.text) Then
         MsgBox("Fill In the required fields")
       End if
  End if
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if txt.text = "" Then
```

change to

```
 if txt.text is nothing Then
```

else, if you dont want it with code, you can try with Error Provider tool.
Then write this code

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text)) Or (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text)) Then
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(textbox1, "This is a require field")
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(textbox2, "This is a require field, fill in with 4 digits")
```

Comment: I can do that but i will have to re-write code for all text boxes in my form!

Answer (score 0):

Your Window is not named window. Put your window's *variable name* instead of the generic Window in your foreach loop. Maybe this is a method of your window class? Although that would be unfortunate and not the best design, you could even omit the name and just write

```
for each txt as Control in yourwindowsvariablename.Controls
```

or

```
for each txt as Control in Controls
```

Comment: The first option brings an error and the second option, 'Controls' is a namespace can i really use it as a type?

Comment: So what is the name of your windows variable? yourwindowsvariablename is just a placeholder for something you have not yet shown us.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in the same form (.net window) as the controls, use `Me.Controls` instead of `window.Controls`. If not check that the `window` actually is a variable.